# Understanding a d3 Multi-Foci Force Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand how this beautiful example works...

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919

I see that clustering is done by the color of the nodes, but I'm confused by the line in question in the collision detection function...

```
r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
```

How can you "add" the product of a comparison of the colors "d.color" and "quad.point.color"?  I would have assumed this would return nothing more than a true/false?  Either way, I'm not sure I follow only this reference to color will have the desired effect of clustering by color?

Anyway, I haven't been able to find any line-by-line description of the workings of the collision detection function, so I'm really hoping that someone here understands it well enough to help explain this bit to me.

All I'm ultimately trying to achieve is to adapt the example to cluster by another non-numeric node attribute (e.g. d.person_name !== quad.point.person_name).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line you are asking about is calculating the allowable distance between nodes, the distance between nodes (`l`) is compared to `r` to determine if there is a collision between `d` and `quad.point`. The value `padding` is added to the allowable distance between nodes if they are of the same colour.  The boolean result is coerced into a Number type by the context.
Instead of assuming what JS does its really easy to open the browser tools and just type the expression in to see what the result is...

[image]

---

But the collision detection is not involved in the clustering, that is handled by this code...

```
// Move nodes toward cluster focus.
function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
    d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
  };
}
```

If you have some data and you want to use the same code to group them by a particular attribute, then you need to add a `cx` and `cy` property to your data such that items with the same attribute value (the value does not need to be numeric) have the same `cx` and `cy` values.

---

### Example (modified version of [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919))

```js
var width = 600,
  height = 200,
  padding = 6, // separation between nodes
  maxRadius = 6;

var n = 200, // total number of nodes
  names = ["Givens", "Crowder", "Lannister", "Baratheon", "Stark"],
  m = names.length; // number of distinct clusters

var color = d3.scale.category10()
  .domain(d3.range(m));

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(names)
  .rangePoints([0, width], 1),

  legend = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("top")


var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
    v = (i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random());
  return {
    radius: Math.sqrt(v) * maxRadius,
    color: color(i),
    cx: x(names[i]),
    cy: height / 2
  };
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .size([width, height])
  .gravity(0)
  .charge(0)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height),
  gLegend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height * 0.9 + ")")
  .call(legend);
gLegend.selectAll(".tick text")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  });


var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.radius;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })
  .call(force.drag);

function tick(e) {
  circle
    .each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
    .each(collide(.5))
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}

// Move nodes toward cluster focus.
function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
    d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
  };
}

// Resolve collisions between nodes.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
      nx1 = d.x - r,
      nx2 = d.x + r,
      ny1 = d.y - r,
      ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
          y = d.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: #000;
}
.x.axis path {
  fill: none;
}
.x.axis text {
  font-family: Papyrus, Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer Cool Blue - really helpful!  Just one more question on using this for a non-numeric attribute.  It seems like all I need to do is create a new scale (instead of the scale "x"), with the same range as x, but a different domain to cover the possible values of d.person_name, and then assign the cx attribute with "cx: personScale(d.person_name)" in the nodes definition.  I'm just not sure how to do that with a scale and can't find it in the API.  E.g. if I have 10 names, where 5 are Bob and 5 are John, then can I somehow turn that into a scale domain range of 0-1?!

Comment: @d3wannabe see my updated answer with a full example including an ordinal scale to group by.

Comment: @d3wannabe, No worries, I had a bit of fun with it :)